# Is the separator part of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've written a custom GridView (UIScrollView Subclass) and decided to use a standard `UITableViewCells` as Cells because they have all the functionality I need.

Everything works fine but I've noticed that sometimes I have a thin gray line at the top of a cell.
I actually thought that the `UITableView` handles the separators of the cells and they actually don't belong to a `UITableViewCell` but it seems to be that I'm wrong.

In fact I want to get rid of them but I don't know how.

Does anyone has experience with this or is the only way to make a custom cell class with the features of a `UITableViewCell`?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, try & error and subview iterating/checking I can tell that the separator is definitely part of an `UITableViewCell`.  Thanks to @Valeriy Van.

> The answer to my first question simply is: **YES**, the separator is
>   part of a `UITableViewCell`.

But it is strictly handled by the `UITableView` and is empty if it is not populated by the TableView.

---

Now to the lines in the image above:

These are **not** separators. They just look like that, such a damn coincidence.

They happen when the Graphics tries to draw something at subpixel-precise coordinates.
This can happen, when the coordinates and/or sizes (the frame) of an visible object (the layer of the view) are between two integer values and the GL tries to render it properly.

Due the "overprecise" frame, the Gl tries to interpolate to integer frames or just not round properly.

So it can happen, like in the picture above, that the first line is stretched or the y-coordinate wrong by one pixel.

This can also happen in a `UITableView` if you return "overprecise" values for cell-heights.

Comment: This was driving me nuts. Good find.

Answer (score 1):

`tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

**Edited:**

Below is a line from UITableView.h
`@property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle; // default is UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`

UITableViewCell, UITableView, UITableViewController designed to work together. And your problem is you try to use UITableViewCell separately. Logically, cells separator is not characteristic of a cell, it's characteristic of a table. That's why separatorStyle is property of UITableView, not UITableViewCell. Well, different approaches are possible, and Apple had chosen this. Look into UITableView.h for how many times 'separator' substring occurs there. Have a look into UITableViewCell.h: UITableViewCell has reference to UITableView. And UITableViewCell coded accurately enough not to crash if _tableView is nil. I think, if _tableView is nil, cell applies same defaults and draws itself with default separator.

What can you do to get rid of separator in you case? If you can't use UITableView in way it was designed, cheat in some way. Try to feed cell with some dumb tableview with properties you need.

Comment: Look in to my eyes and tell me honestly that you have read my question.

Comment: I believe this is a valid answer to your question, that is how you get rid of separators...which is what you are asking.

Comment: It's not. I clearly stated, that i'm not using a UITableView.

Comment: @yinkou, despite you are not very polite, I'll answer your question. UITableViewCell, UITableView, UITableViewController designed to work together. And your problem is you try to use UITableViewCell separately. Logically, cells separator is not characteristic of cell, it's characteristic of table. That's why separatorStyle is property of UITable view. Look into UITableView.h for how many tymes 'separator' substring occurs there. Have a look into UITableViewCell.h: UITableViewCell has reference to UITableView. And  UITableViewCell coded accurately enough not to crash if _tableView is nil.

Comment: I'm sorry Valeriy, i didn't want to be rude. But from my point of view you were the unpolite one. Because it seemed to me, that you have tried to answer the question before you even had read and understood the actual question. But never mind that.

Comment: I haven't used any TableView and i thought i clearly stated that. Anyway you are right about that those things are designed to work together but i can easily misuse a Cell for other things.